# Edit Toolbar Became Disabled While Editing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing, toolbar

My edit toolbar became disabled while I was editing a layer in QGIS. I have closed the window and opened it again to edit, but it is still disabled.

Comment: What version of QGIS?

Comment: Which version you are using ?? I am using 1.8.0 & its working fine for me..

Comment: What sort of layer were you editing?  Shapefile, PostGIS, something else?

Comment: Keep in mind that the layer to be edited must be selected in the layer list.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe too obvious an answer, but it's what I needed when googling for this so...

*"All editing sessions start by choosing the [image] 'Toggle editing' option"*

*"By default, QGIS loads layers read-only: This is a safeguard to avoid accidentally editing a layer if there is a slip of the mouse. However, you can choose to edit any layer as long as the data provider supports it, and the underlying data source is writable (i.e. its files are not read-only). "*

https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#digitizing-an-existing-layer

Comment: And to spell it out even further (my problem): "as long as the data provider supports it, and the underlying data source is writable" - I was importing a geojson file, and could not enable edit mode until, at this hint, I right-clicked the layer and saved it as a separate file (which created a new, editable layer).

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. In my case I had a Shapefile imported as Layer and defined a "Filter" on this Layer. **Clearing the filter rule** enabled the "Edit Button" again!

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem too. I was trying to edit some MapInfo TAB files but even the 'Toggle editing' option was disable. Then I translated my files into Shapefile and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with one particular shapefile (maybe it was protected by its vendor). My solution was to select all features and save the selection as a vector file (i.e. new shapefile) - in the "Layer" section of QGIS 2.2.0 top menu. The new shapefile layer is editable.

Answer (score 0):

Do not browse your layer from the zipped folder! First unzip the folder, then browse your layer from the unzipped folder. Now toggle editing tool should work properly.